# (SQL) How would I return the result set from multiple executed stored procedures?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Okay I have a queswtion about returning the recordset from multiple stored procedures.

If I have a sproc which does this:

```
exec sproc1
exec sproc2
exec sproc3
```

Each sproc returns just one number, so it return

[no column name]
1500

[no column name]
18000

[no column name]
1253

Obviously a datareader won't be able to handle this, or at least I don't think it will.  So I thought about declaring a Table variable

```
DECLARE @Table (Col1, Col2)

INSERT INTO @Table
exec sproc1,exec sproc2, etc...)
```

But that doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread your INSERTs over several statements:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Value int);

INSERT INTO @t
EXEC sproc1;

INSERT INTO @t
EXEC sproc2;

INSERT INTO @t
EXEC sproc3;

SELECT Value FROM @t;
```

**Edit**

Wait ... are you saying that you already have a stored procedure which returns multiple resultsets? DataReaders can definitely handle that. Just use the [NextResult()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.nextresult.aspx) method to tell the reader that you now want data from the next resultset.

**Edit 2**

You asked if there's a way to roll all the results into one row. I can think of one way to do this but it's definitely not pretty, and I'm sure I'll be chastised by more SQL-savvy users in the comments, but here goes:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Id int identity, Value int);

INSERT INTO @t (Value)
EXEC sproc1;

INSERT INTO @t (Value)
EXEC sproc2;

INSERT INTO @t (Value)
EXEC sproc3;

SELECT Value FROM @t
PIVOT ( AVG(Value) FOR Id IN ([1], [2], [3]) ) AS t;
```

So that inserts the three values as separate rows, and then pivots on the Id values to create a single row with three columns.

Comment: In one *row*? Multiple result sets? I suppose you could add an identity column to @t and pivot on it to turn the columns into rows or something.